# regular expressions in python, matching words outside of html tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to match a phrase using regular expressions, so long as none of the words in that phrase appear within an html tag.

For this example, I am using the following url:

```
   url = "http://www.sidley.com/people/results.aspx?lastname=B"
```

The regexp that I am using is:

```
   regexp = "Babb(?!([^<]+)?>).+?Jonathan(?!([^<]+)?>).+?C(?!([^<]+)?>)"
   page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
   re.findall(regexp, page, re.DOTALL)
```

With that regexp, I get the following output:

```
   [('', '', '')]
```

When I change the regexp to (*note the outer parens):

```
   regexp = "(Babb(?!([^<]+)?>).+?Jonathan(?!([^<]+)?>).+?C(?!([^<]+)?>))"
   page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
   re.findall(regexp, page, re.DOTALL)
```

I get:

```
   [('Babb, Jonathan C', '', '', '')]
```

I am confused as to why this is.

1) Why am I getting these empty strings as matches?
2) Why for the first regexp, do I not get the actual match?

and finally,

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What information are you trying to get out the given website? Are you supposed to use only regex?

Comment: I can do this any way I want.  I have been doing it another way, without using regex, and its a very time consuming process.  I decided to switch over to regex, because I thought I could make it much faster.  Basically, I want to take any phrase, and find whether it exists in a page (so long as it exists outside of the html).  So, if I sent "I like dogs, but not cats", I would want to find out whether that phrase exists on the page.  So, my regexp might look like this: "I(?!([^<]+)?>).+?like(?!([^<]+)?>).+?dogs....."

Comment: Have you checked out Beautiful Soup? it is a python library to parse html and it has a specific function called get_text() which removes html tags. Removing the tags before searching for text might be easier.

Comment: I want it to return the actual portion of text from the html page, so i can get a start and end location.  if i modify the html page, my resulting locations will be incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting empty strings is that you are using *non-greedy*. If you don't want that information, just remove some of your parentheses. In fact, you should really look into non-grouping parentheses or just some of the extraneous pairs.

---

The final code that I would use (for the whole process) would be

```
import re
import urllib2


url = 'http://www.sidley.com/people/results.aspx?lastname=B'
regexp = 'Babb(?!<+?>).+?Jonathan(?!<+?>).+?C(?!<+?>)'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
re.findall(regexp, page, re.DOTALL)
```

A breakdown of the regexp:

- We select for the first word.  `Babb`
- We *don't* want to match any HTML tags, so we use a must-not-match anti-group. `(?!)`
- Within this, we place a regexp that selects for an HTML tag (not quite sure why it is this particular expression that works, rather than `.+?>`). `<+?>`
- We select for at least one more character, non-greedily. `.+?`
- We repeat this process for each of the other words (`Jonathan` and `C`).

Comment: Worked!  new regexp is Babb(?![^<]+?>).+?Jonathan(?![^<]+?>).+?C(?![^<]+?>), got rid of some of the inner parens.  Unfortunately, I have limited knowledge of how regex actually does its thing, so I am not sure why this worked.  But I guess practice makes perfect.

Comment: Take a look at the explanation I added, hopefully that will help you. However, that one part still puzzles me. Regexps are rather brain-boggling sometimes...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Do you foresee a major problem to changing the .+? to .*?.  I can foresee situations where we have don't have any spaces between the words except for the html tags (maybe a <br />.  In that case, the above would fail, right?

Comment: No, because the br tag is 6 characters :) Also I finally figured out the regexp -- you are trying to avoid stuff like `"Punch <and /> Judy"` from matching (not `"Punch <a href='blah'>and</a> Judy"`, correct?